# Why do I get an error when I write a traditional function as an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I wrote a very simple addition function. The first code was written with the traditional function. But I want to write the same code with arrow function, but a red error appears under the arrow sign and when I want to see the result with console.log, I get a meaningless error. Why? and How do I write this function in its simplest form with the arrow function? Thanks!!

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sImVh.png)

```
    // First way

function total(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(total(5,2)); // Will print total "7"


// Second way

total(a, b) => {
  return  a + b;      // **Will I get an error when I print console.log(total(5,2))! Why?**
}
```

Comment: `let total = (a, b) => ...` - the main issue was the missing `=`, but you should always explicitly declare your variables with `let`/`const`. Voting to close as a typo. More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#examples)

Comment: Hey Rory,
Thank you so much! My conclusions from what you said:

When I write with the traditional method, I don't need to assign const or let to the total variable. But since I'm writing with arrow, I need to assign const or let. 

Well, when I want to write with arrow function, the simplest version is "const total = (a, b) => a + b;" is this, is it correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

you are having the syntax error, for an arrow function you need to provide the variable which stores the value for the function here`(total)`, then the parameters that needs to be passed `a,b` and then your function body.

```
const total = (a, b) => {
  return  a + b;      
}
console.log(total(5,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total(a, b) => {
  return  a + b;   
}
```

this is error because you have not declared any variable.arrow function takes a variable then parameter and then the logics that you want to put .

so make your arrow function like :-

```
let total = (a,b) =>{
return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error.

This is the correct way:

```
const total = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
}
```

or

```
const total = (a, b) => a + b;
```